# clicks on blazor webpage not being registered after tab reload

Tags: javascript, delphi, chromium-embedded, cef4delphi

I am just getting started with CEF4Delphi. I have a chromium window on a tab in a page control. There are javascript hooks attached to elements on the webpage which register clicks and fire off native delphi code. This is all working correctly on one webpage. I can switch tabs and keep clicking on the webpage and receiving the click events.

However, when loading a different webpage there is some strange behaviour. The first time the tab is loaded clicks will be registered just fine. The issue arises when switching tabs. The second time a tab is loaded there are no clicks being registered.

This second webpage is being created by blazor which is different to the first but I am not sure why that would be affecting it.

I have tested using Google.com and it works fine on there also.

```
Chromium1.LoadURL('localhost:6064');
```

is run when the tab is loaded.

```
class procedure TmyExtension.ButtonClick(const data: string);
var
  msg: ICefProcessMessage;
begin
  msg := TCefProcessMessageRef.New('ButtonClick');

  TCefv8ContextRef.Current.Browser.MainFrame.SendProcessMessage(PID_BROWSER, msg);
end;
```

The delphi code being fired

```
Chromium1.browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(
          'document.getElementById("'+
          'NewButton' +
          '").addEventListener("click", function(evt){' +
          'function getpath(n){var ret = n.id;' +
            'if (n.parentNode){return "" + ret}' +
            'else return ret};'
          'myextension.ButtonClick(getpath(evt.target))' +
          '})', Chromium1.browser.MainFrame.GetURL, 0);
```

The Javascript being executed

```
procedure TtabWebPage.Chromium1ProcessMessageReceived(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; const frame: ICefFrame;
  sourceProcess: TCefProcessId; const message: ICefProcessMessage;
  out Result: Boolean);
begin
  if (message = nil) or (message.ArgumentList = nil) then exit;

  // This function receives the messages with the JavaScript results
  if (message.Name = 'ButtonClick') then  begin
    Inc(FCount);
    Result := True;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Receiving the chromium message and increasing a count.

There doesn't seem to be a way to debug whether the javascript is being run. The ExecuteJavaScript function is definitely being run every time the page loads. I am wondering if there is anything to do with the blazor aspect of the webpage that causes this, or if there is any way to debug the issue.

Comment: I don't see anything 'blazor' here nor how that could fit in. Better elaborate on that aspect or change the title.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not up to date with how blazor works, but from what I can tell the only difference with the websites is that aspect. I just need to know if there is anything within the blazor process that interferes with javascript injection/ chromium extensions not working after refreshing the page.

Comment: Blazor server-side (SignalR) or Blazor client-side (WebAssembly) ?  Check if `mono.wasm` is downloaded.

Comment: Does your contraption work with an Angular app?  Google.com doesn't look like the toughest test.

Comment: tested on angular.io and paypal.com just now, works fine.

Comment: And are you sure those are Angular apps?

Comment: I believe it is SignalR that is being used. I can't be sure but they came up in the search for angular sites.